# WHERE with RANDOM in postgres wrong?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query like this

```
select * from (select generate_series(1, 1030) as id) t where id=floor(random() * 1030 + 1)
```

Why this query return more than one row?
You can replace

```
(select generate_series(1, 1030) as id) t
```

with any table have field id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening here is that the call to `random()` in your `WHERE` clause is happening once for each record examined.  Instead, put the random logic into a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT generate_series(1, 1030) AS id
) t
WHERE id = (SELECT FLOOR(RANDOM() * 1030 + 1));
```

By the way, the reason the above trick works is because Postgres' optimizer will execute the subquery once and cache the result.  If it *didn't* do this, then the above would still suffer from the same problem you are currently seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Because `random()` is defined as "volatile", which means it's evaluated for every row in the statement. If you want to pick one row, you need to "hide" the random function in a subselect:

```
select * 
from generate_series(1, 1030) as t(id) 
where id=(select floor(random() * 1030 + 1))
```